# How to use arrayfun for the custom multiplication of two multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a three dimensional domain in MATLAB. For each point in the domain I have defined four arrays of size `(NX,NY,NZ)` at each point of the domain:

```
A1; % size(A1) = [NX NY NZ]
A2; % size(A2) = [NX NY NZ]
A3; % size(A3) = [NX NY NZ]
B;  % size(B ) = [NX NY NZ]
```

Now I want to construct array `C` of size `[NX NY NZ 3 1]` which is defined for each point in the three dimensional domain:

```
C(i, j, k, 1, 1) =  A1(i, j, k)*B(i, j, k);
C(i, j, k, 2, 1) =  A2(i, j, k)*B(i, j, k);
C(i, j, k, 3, 1) =  A3(i, j, k)*B(i, j, k);
% In other words:
C(i, j, k, :, :) = [A1(i, j, k)*B(i, j, k);
                    A2(i, j, k)*B(i, j, k);
                    A3(i, j, k)*B(i, j, k)]
```

I tried the following but it does not work.

```
C = arrayfun(@(a1,a2,a3,b)([a1*b; a2*b; a3*b]), A1, A2, A3, B, 'UniformOutput', 'false');
```

After running the above statement, I get:

```
Error using arrayfun
All of the input arguments must be of the same size and shape.
Previous inputs had 3 dimensions. Input #6 has 2.
```

Maybe I am not approaching my problem correctly and `arrayfun` is not the function for this task. Could someone kindly shed light on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
C = bsxfun(@times, cat(4,A1,A2,A3), B);
```

Or do it directly:

```
C = cat(4, A1.*B, A2.*B, A3.*B);
```